# Sending Large Message Size with MQTT Leads to Missing Messages

Tags: c++, mqtt

I'm using Eclipse Paho MQTT C client library to publish and subscribe to messages on the same machine. The messages are sent from the AIMSUN traffic simulator program every simulation step ranging from 0.1 second simulation time to 1 second simulation time.

An external application is subscribed to these messages and are always listening for new messages. With the GUI enabled, which displays the cars, the simulation runs expectedly slower and the interval between receiving messages from the traffic simulator program matches the duration of the simulation step. However, running the simulation via command line without the GUI results in many lost messages though the simulation completes quicker.

The interval between receiving messages from the traffic simulator program is about 13 times as long as with the GUI open. For example, if the simulation step is 1 sec, the external application should expect the message every second, but it receives it every 13 seconds. I tried to troubleshoot and found out that reducing the message size to zero caused received message frequency to go up and match the simulation duration. I have tried different QOS levels and the results are about the same. My best guess right now is that MQTT publishers must wait until the previous message is sent before sending again. But I have tried setting publisher and subscriber's QOS to 0 whose "fire and forget" mode should preempt this problem. I'm a novice with MQTT and would appreciate any ideas on what could be going on behind the scenes.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to really be able to help. But what I can say is that you should NOT be doing long running tasks in the subscribers message handler. If you have long running tasks you should be locally queuing the incoming message and handling that on a separate thread.

Comment: thanks the subscriber message handling is on a separate thread